# Trying to Compile odbc_fdw postgres extention for win64

Tags: postgresql, foreign-data-wrapper

I want to compile this: https://github.com/bluthg/odbc_fdw for Windows. I have tried the instructions and searched all over but can't figure it out.

No matter what I do I get:

```
Makefile:31: C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk'.  Stop.
```

If I use PGSX

```
Makefile:35: ../../src/Makefile.global: No such file or directory
Makefile:36: /contrib/contrib-global.mk: No such file or directory
```

If I don't use PGSX=1

I get that I need PGSX to tell the compiler what to do or feed it that information manually but I can't seem to do either.

Thanks for the help

Comment: What toolchain/compiler are you trying to use? Anyway: Most instructions won't consider or care about Windows. It's a pain. PGXS isn't really supported on Windows. Extensions are generally compiled by putting them in a PostgreSQL source tree and doing an in-tree build with MSVC. However, you can also do out-of-tree builds; [here's a simple example I wrote earlier](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/compiling-postgresql-extensions-visual-studio-windows/).

Comment: Hi Craig, I was able to follow your example in VS2008 and compile but odbc_fdw wants a bunch of other funky things to build and throws errors. 
Thanks for the help, I'll bang my head on this a little more but I doubt I will be able to avoid using a 3rd program to move information between the 2 databases.
I was using make with Cygwin.